# File Pointer Position

Tags: c, file-io

Here is the snippet of code

```
typedef struct
{
   double testA;
   double testB[500];   
   bool isProcessed;
} MYSTURCT;
```

I have a binary file which is written with multiple structs of type "myStruct".

Now, in another function, I m trying to read the file and update in the middle.

```
void test()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen (testFile, "r+")

    MYSTURCT* myPtr = malloc (sizeof (MYSTRUCT));

    while ( fread (myPtr,sizeof(MYSTRUCT),1,fp) )
    {
        if (!myPtr->isProcessed)
        {
            //update some thing int he struct

            myPtr->testA = 100.00;

            fseek (fp, -sizeof(MYSTRUCT), SEEK_CUR);

            fwrite (myPtr,sizeof(MYSTRUCT), 1,fp);

        }
    }
}
```

Once I find something unprocessed, I update the struct in the memory, then try to 
write the struct to the disk. (first by seeking the CURR - sizeof(struct)) position
and then fwriting the struct to disk.

Whats happening in my application is after doing the fseek, my

fp->_ptr is getting messed up and it looses the track of position in my stream.

Is there anything wrong that I am doing here?

Comment: I am trying to traverse thru all my "MyStrucs" that are written in the binary file. After doing the first fseek, since my ptr got messed up, I was no longer able to traverse all of them correctly

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem, but I noticed you're opening the file "r+" instead of "r+b", so it treats it as text instead of binary for some functions. I doubt that matters with fread/fwrite though.

Answer (score 4):

`-sizeof(STRUCT)` is potentially dangerous. `sizeof(STRUCT)` is an unsigned type, and if it is as least as wide as an int it's promoted type (the type of the `-sizeof(STRUCT)` expression) will also be unsigned and have a value of about `UINT_MAX - sizeof(STRUCT) + 1` or possibly `ULONG_MAX - sizeof(STRUCT)+ 1`.

If you're unlucky (e.g. 32 bit size_t, 64 bit long) its `UINT_MAX - sizeof(STRUCT) + 1` and a `long int` may be able to hold this large postive value and the seek won't do what you want it to do.

You could consider doing a position save and restore:

```
fpos_t pos;

if (fgetpos(fp, &pos) != 0)
{
    /* position save failed */
    return;
}

/* read struct */

if (fsetpos(fp, &pos) != 0)
{
    /* position restore failed */
    return;
}

/* write struct */
```

`fgetpos` and `fsetpos` use a `fpos_t` so can potentially work with very large files in scenarios where `fseek` and `ftell` won't.

Comment: A question I asked last month touches on this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269019

Answer (score 2):

The fopen manpage says:

> Reads and writes may be intermixed on
>   read/write streams in any  order.
>          Note  that  ANSI  C requires that a file positioning function
>   intervene
>          between output and input, unless an input operation encounters 
>   end-of-
>          file.   (If this condition is not met, then a read is allowed to
>   return
>          the result of writes other than the most recent.)  Therefore it is
>   good
>          practice  (and  indeed  sometimes  necessary  under  Linux) 
>   to  put an
>          fseek(3) or fgetpos(3) operation between write and read 
>   operations  on
>          such  a  stream.   This  operation  may  be  an  apparent 
>   no-op (as in
>          fseek(..., 0L, SEEK_CUR) called for its synchronizing side effect.

So you might try putting the dummy fseek in right after you fwrite.

Comment: The problem that seems to happen is, my fp->_ptr which actually stores the pointer to the location in the file gets corrupted immediately after doing fseek. Even when I donot do fwrite, just doing fseek is creating problem. My struct is a big struct with multiple elements. I am trying to figure out if I am providing the wrong argument in the size. But not sure.

Comment: You seem to have misspelled MYSTRUCT in a few places. Hopefully that's just an issue with your post and not your code :). If you don't mind, try putting in a "long offset = -sizeof(MYSTRUCT)" in before the seek and then print that value. sizeof normally returns an unsigned number, but hopefully your compiler can figure that out...

Answer (score 1):

Try fflush after the last fwrite(). Then Try making a new test file using your current structure. It could be that you changed your structure and your current test file has an older invalid byte order.

Comment: Could it be that the "bool isProcessed" is not using up a complete 32 bits. It there a byte boundary issue? Did you reorder the types inside the MYSTURCT struct. If so start with a newly created file.

Comment: Make a new test file based on your latest build and do the temporary char substitution that rascher did to make the struct fill the byte boundary.

Comment: This did the trick. The inherent problem was fwrite followed by fread as mentioned by kwatford in the earlier answer. To solve the issue, I just put fflush() after fwrite and it worked.

WHen I was debugging, I was looking at fp->_ptr value and I think, it was not a good idea. FSEEK doesnot set this value after the call. To me, I assumed it was corrupted (which was not)

Answer (score 1):

You malloc `sizeof (MYSTRUCT)` bytes to myPtr, but myPtr is of type MYSTURCT.

I don't think that's your problem, though.

Apparently there's nothing wrong with your code; try to add some error-checking ...

```
void test(){
    FILE* fp = fopen (testFile, "r+"); /* missing semicolon */
    MYSTURCT* myPtr = malloc (sizeof *myPtr);
    while ( fread (myPtr,sizeof *myPtr,1,fp) == 1) /* error checking */
    {
        if (!myPtr->isProcessed)
        {
            //update some thing int he struct
            myPtr->testA = 100.00;
            if (fseek (fp, -sizeof *myPtr, SEEK_CUR) == -1)
            {
                perror("fseek");
            }
            if (fwrite (myPtr,sizeof *myPtr, 1,fp) != 1)
            {
                perror("fwrite");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the fopen should be in binary mode, even if you're on Linux (where it really doesn't matter). On Windows a sequence of 0x0D 0x0A in the middle of one of those doubles will get converted to 0x0D and mess everything up.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your sample code, and it seems to work fine to me (though I am doing it in C - I substituted a "char" for your "boolean")

For debugging, how do you know that the fp is getting corrupted? It is unusual to look at the members of the FILE struct. Each time you do an fseek(), fread() or fwrite(), what is your output when you invoke ftell()?

Comment: I started my task in the debugger and put a break pt, that was one way I came to know it was getting corrupted. Other way, I printed fp->_ptr in hex before and after..

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to write to the file you should use "w+b" not "r+" otherwise fwrite would fail and return the error code instead. (I think).

Comment: you can write to a file using "r+" mode