# What type for subtracting 2 size_t's?

Tags: c, size-t

Which type in C should be used to represent the difference between two objects' sizes?

As `size_t` is unsigned, something like

```
size_t diff = sizeof (small_struct) - sizeof (big_struct);
```

obviously wouldn't be correct and it seems to me there's no real signed equivalent.

`ptrdiff_t` sounds kind of tempting, but

1. like its name says it's for subtracting pointers.
2. I've read that e.g. segmented platforms like DOS have a maximal object size of 64k which is representable by 16-bit. Far pointers, however, are composed of a 16-bit segment value and a 16-bit offset value. Wouldn't that make `ptrdiff_t` on such a platform 32-bit as well?
   If so, the difference between two objects in size only required 16-bit, but using ptrdiff_t would give you a 32-bit wide variable, making it sub-optimal.

So, what's a suitable, portable type for working with such a value?

`Edit:`
I know about ssize_t, but it's

1. not part of standard C.
2. actually not intended for such use, but for returning either a size or a (negative) error value.

Comment: `ssize_t` is signed `size_t`

Comment: @AFAIK `ssize_t` is POSIX, not ISO C.

Comment: @RomanR. `ssize_t` is not C Standard and a value of `size_t` is not guaranteed to fit in `ssize_t` in POSIX.

Comment: Any specific reason you want a negative number? You could just do `size_t diff = a > b ? a - b : b - a;` otherwise.

Comment: The trouble with the question is that it doesn't explain what it is supposed to mean.  You can envision adding structure sizes somewhat, for calculating layout for example, although it is quite troublesome already due to structure alignment rules.  What does the difference in structure sizes really represent?  In what context does this code appear?  If you can't explain that then you can't write correct code for it either.

Comment: `ptrdiff_t` is suitable for this, although I don't have anything to say about the optimality.

Comment: @Mehrdad: C11, 6.5.7/9: *"When two pointers are subtracted, [...] The size of the result is implementation-defined,
 and its type (a signed integer type) is ptrdiff_t defined in the <stddef.h> header.
  If the result is not representable in an object of that type, the behavior is undefined."* So, there's no guarantee (although this refers to pointer addresses, since that's what `ptrdiff_t` is for, not object sizes).

Comment: @netcoder: That's correct, but it's not the whole story. You can't subtract arbitrary pointers; they have to be pointing to the same object. So if `ptrdiff_t` can hold their difference (let's say one pointer is to the beginning of the object and the other one is to the end of the object), and `size_t` can hold the size of the object, by definition converting between the two cannot lose information. Whether or not it overflows the sign bit, though, is of course a different issue -- but the bits are there.

Comment: Related:  [What should happen to the negation of a size_t (i.e. `-sizeof(struct foo)`))?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269019/what-should-happen-to-the-negation-of-a-size-t-i-e-sizeofstruct-foo)

Comment: What do you want to use the difference for?

Comment: @RomanR `ssize_t` is only required to be able to hold -1 apart from non-negative values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't a standard datatype that's guaranteed to be 100% safe for what you're trying to do. For evidence, imagine if `size_t` is really just `uint64_t`, which is entirely possible. Then there's no standard C data type that is guaranteed to have a positive range that matches `uint64_t` and also handles negative values.

**So the blunt answer to your question is "no datatype" (assuming strict adherence to standard C, which you seem to be desiring).**

You're not clear on your use-case, however, and it's possible you may be able to take advantage of modular arithmetic to handle "negative" values. For example, [the following code](http://ideone.com/L4Y1ih) results in `d2` being `4` because of modular arithmetic, allowing the code to act as if `size_t` were signed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    size_t d1 = sizeof(int32_t) - sizeof(int64_t);
    size_t d2 = sizeof(int64_t) + d1; // Add difference (even if d1 is "negative"*)

    printf("d1: %zu\n", d1);
    printf("d2: %zu\n", d2);

    return 0;
    // * By "negative" I mean that d1 would be negative if size_t were signed
}
```

Modular arithmetic may not be enough for you in your case, but for others it may.

Answer (score 18):

When I am really worried about overflow issues like that (especially when working in modular arithmetic where "negative" values wrap somewhere other than `~0`) I just split it into two cases:

```
if (a > b) {
    size_t diff = a - b;
} else {
    size_t diff = b - a;
    // code here subtracts diff rather than adds it, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no signed C integer type that can hold all the values from a `size_t` value.

Comment: In your implementation? Or is it specifically forbidden by the Standard? :)

Comment: I meant in all implementations. There are of course implementations where all `size_t` values can fit in a signed integer type.

Answer (score -2):

You could do this:

```
size_t diff = std::abs(static_cast <int> (sizeof (small_struct) - sizeof (big_struct)));
```