# Is it safe to take the difference of two size_t objects?

Tags: c++, size-t

I'm investigating a standard for my team around using `size_t` vs `int` (or `long`, etc). The biggest drawback I've seen pointed out is that taking the difference of two size_t objects can cause problems (I'm unsure of specific problems -- maybe something wasn't 2s complemented and the signed/unsigned angers the compiler). I wrote a quick program in C++ using the V120 VS2013 compiler that allowed me to do the following:

```
#include <iostream>

main()
{
    size_t a = 10;
    size_t b = 100;
    int result = a - b;
}
```

The program resulted in `-90`, which although correct, makes me nervous about type mismatches, signed/unsigned problems, or just plain undefined behavior if the size_t happens to get used in complex math.

**My question is if it's safe to do math with size_t objects, specifically, taking the difference?** I'm considering using size_t as a standard for things like indexes. I've seen some interesting posts on the topic here, but they don't address the math issue (or I missed it).

[What type for subtracting 2 size_t's?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14202241/4183920)

[typedef for a signed type that can contain a size_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19352403/4183920)

Comment: If the subtraction results in a negative number, [it will wrap around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269019/what-should-happen-to-the-negation-of-a-size-t-i-e-sizeofstruct-foo) according to [two's compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: The way you have it, no it is not safe. But not because of the math itself. You are casting a `size_t` result (which is likely to be `unsigned long`) to a `int` (signed), which is likely to be a smaller datatype.

Comment: The corresponding difference type of size_t is ptrdiff_t, not int

Comment: @DieterLücking actually, the corresponding type is still `size_t`, not that it helps the OP any.

Comment: In all unsigned/signed conversions, it should be performed explicitly, with intent by the programmer, who is very sure about the range of values for the arguments so you don't end up with [overflow like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14afc0a42256ce1b)

Comment: @MadPhysicist - re: "You are casting ...", there's no cast there. There's a **conversion**. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Comment: @PeteBecker you are absolutely right. My nomenclature was very sloppy there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is not guaranteed to work portably, but is not UB either. The code must run without error, but the resulting `int` value is implementation defined. So as long as you are working on platforms that guarantee the desired behavior, this is fine (as long as the difference can be represented by an `int` of course), otherwise, just use signed types everywhere (see last paragraph).

Subtracting two `std::size_t`s will yield a new `std::size_t`<sup>†</sup> and its value will be determined by wrapping. In your example, assuming 64 bit `size_t`, `a - b` will equal `18446744073709551526`. This does not fit into an (commonly used 32 bit) `int`, so an implementation defined value is assigned to `result`.

To be honest, I would recommend to not use unsigned integers for anything but bit magic. Several members of the standard committee agree with me: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Interactive-Panel-Ask-Us-Anything 9:50, 42:40, 1:02:50

Rule of thumb (paraphrasing Chandler Carruth from the above video): If you could count it yourself, use `int`, otherwise use `std::int64_t`.

---

<sup>†</sup>Unless its conversion rank is less than `int`, e.g. if `std::size_t` is `unsigned short`. In that case, the result is an `int` and everything will work fine (unless `int` is not wider than `short`). However

1. I do not know of any platform that does this.
2. This would still be platform specific, see first paragraph.

Comment: There are many platforms where `sizeof(int)==sizeof(short)` and `sizeof(int)==sizeof(size_t)` (all 16 bits). That is nearly on every 8 and 16 Bit microcontroller the case (AVR, PIC10-18, MSP430, ...)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't use `size_t`, you are screwed: `size_t` is the one type that exists to be used for memory sizes, and which is consequently guaranteed to always be big enough for that purpose. (`uintptr_t` is quite similar, but it's neither the first such type, nor is it used by the standard libraries, nor is it available without including `stdint.h`.) If you use an `int`, you can get undefined behavior when your allocations exceed 2GiB of address space (or 32kiB if you are on a platform where `int` is only 16 bits!), even though the machine has more memory and you are executing in 64 bit mode.

If you need a difference of `size_t` that may become negative, use the signed variant `ssize_t`.

Comment: "use the signed variant `ssize_t`"... how?  Would you cast before or after subtraction?  What about the lost range?

Comment: @BenVoigt The lost range with `ssize_t` is one bit, the lost range of `int` is frequently 32 bit, it may even be 48 bit (if `int` is 16 bit and `size_t` is 64 bit). Ergo: Using `ssize_t` is definitely much better than using `int`.

Comment: @BenVoigt It does not really matter when you do the cast: If you get overflow, you are screwed anyway, with both `int` and `ssize_t`. All sanity checks must be done before the difference is calculated.

Comment: If `uintptr_t` cannot hold any memory size that `size_t` can hold, I will eat my shorts.

Comment: @Kaz Good point. I removed the word `only` and replaced it by a note about `uintptr_t`. Hope that makes you happy :-)

Comment: You do not need 2GiB or more for undefined behavior, 32KiB is enough on some platforms.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Good point, even though I had meant those number to be only a motivating example. I have added a remark on smaller `int` sizes now, hope you like it :-)

Answer (score 5):

The `size_t` type is unsigned. The subtraction of any two `size_t` values is defined-behavior

However, firstly, the result is implementation-defined if a larger value is subtracted from a smaller one. The result is the mathematical value, reduced to the smallest positive residue modulo `SIZE_T_MAX + 1`. For instance if the largest value of `size_t` is 65535, and the result of subtracting two `size_t` values is -3, then the result will be 65536 - 3 = 65533.   On a different compiler or machine with a different `size_t`, the numeric value will be different.

Secondly, a `size_t` value might be out of range of the type `int`. If that is the case, we get a second implementation-defined result arising from the forced conversion.  In this situation, any behavior can apply; it just has to be documented by the implementation, and the conversion must not fail. For instance, the result could be clamped into the `int` range, producing `INT_MAX`.  A common behavior seen  on two's complement machines (virtually all) in the conversion of wider (or equal width) unsigned types to narrower signed types is simple bit truncation: enough bits are taken from the unsigned value to fill the signed value, including its sign bit.

Because of the way two's complement works, if the original arithmetically correct abstract result itself fits into `int`, then the conversion will produce that result.

For instance, suppose that the subtraction of a pair of 64 bit `size_t` values on a two's complement machine yields the abstract arithmetic value -3, which is becomes the positive value `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD`.   When this is coerced into a 32 bit `int`, then the common behavior seen in many compilers for two's complement machines is that the lower 32 bits are taken as the image of the resulting `int`: `0xFFFFFFFD`. And, of course, that is just the value -3 in 32 bits.

So the upshot is, that **your code is *de facto* quite portable** because virtually all mainstream machines are two's complement with conversion rules based on sign extension and bit truncation, including between signed and unsigned.

Except that sign extension doesn't occur when a value is widened while converting from unsigned to signed. Thus he one problem is the rare situation in which `int` is wider than `size_t`. If a 16 bit `size_t` result is 65533, due to 4 being subtracted from 1, this will not produce a -3 when converted to a 32 bit `int`; it will produce 65533!

Comment: Perhaps you mean "implementation-dependent" rather than "implementation-defined"?  The latter term has a formal meaning assigned by the C++ standard.

Comment: Also, your last paragraph forgot to consider the integral promotions which are performed before subtraction takes place.

Comment: @BenVoigt Right; but that's going to be rare. How common is it for `size_t` to correspond to `unsigned short` or `unsigned char`?  Still, valid point. As far as "implementation-defined result" goes, that usage is ingrained into me from ISO C.  Everything in this answer applies to C and C++.