# Why worry about 'undefined behavior' in >> of signed type?

Tags: c++, c, hardware, bit-manipulation, undefined-behavior

My question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059480/how-to-write-a-constant-time-function-to-copy-the-most-significant-bit-to-all-bi) and will contain few questions.

For me the most obvious (means I would use it in my code) solution to above problem is just this:

```
uint8_t x = some value;
x = (int8_t)x >> 7;
```

Yes, yes I hear you all .... undefined behavior and this is why I've not posted my 'solution'.

I have a feeling (maybe it is only my sick mind) that term 'undefined behavior' is overused on SO just to justify downvoting someone if question is tagged c/c++.

So - let's (for a while) put aside C/C++ standards and think about everyday life/programming, real compiler implementations and code they generate for contemporary hardware.

Taking into account the following:

- As far as I remember all the hardware I had encountered had distinct instructions for arithmetic and logical shift.
- All compilers that I know translate `>>` into arithmetic shift for signed types and logical shift for unsigned types.
- I cannot recall any compiler ever emitting `div`-like low level instruction when `>>` was used in c/c++ code (and we are not talking about operator overloading here).
- All the hardware I know use U2.

So ... is there anything (any contemporary compiler, hardware) that behaves differently than mentioned above? Put simply should I ever be worried about right shifting signed value not being translated to arithmetic shift?

My 'solution' compiles to just one low level instruction on many platforms while others require multiple low level instructions. What would you use in your code?

Truth please ;-)

Comment: Why don't you like my question and want to close? I am really interested in real life experience of others on various platforms and with compilers I have not used.

Comment: According to C11 (§6.5.7 p 5) using signed-types in a right-shift is not undefined but *implementation-defined* behaviour.

Comment: I don't get *what you don't get* in **undefined** as in undefined behavior. Your PC might jump up and catch fire, and you might get nasal demons. If your compiler guarantees something, you can rely on that, but *only on that particular compiler*.

Comment: You are wrong thinking that the compiler translates the instructions one by one. The compiler considers the _whole_ program, and compiles/optimizes it as a whole. Necessary reading: [[1](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)], [[2](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html)], [[3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html)].

Comment: @Vlad: I am really aware of that.

Comment: @Artur: but you say "compilers that I know translate `>>` into arithmetic shift". This implies thinking in terms of operations, not the whole program.

Comment: Adding to @Kninnug's comment, C++11 says the same: `E1 >> E2` "If `E1`
has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined."

Comment: @hvd: I know what standard says about right shift on signed and this is why I am mentioning undefined bahavior in my question.

Comment: @Artur I don't think you do. My point, and Kninnug's, is that there is no undefined behaviour when you right-shift a negative integer, so if you understand that, why do you mention undefined behaviour? :)

Comment: @Artur This is not a case of undefined behavior - it is implementation-specified. `-1 >> 3` is a valid expression: it will evaluate to some integer value as opposed to producing nasal demons.

Comment: Closing this question as opinion-based is weak sauce.  There are legitimate reasons not to write code that exhibits UB, and closing this question for that reason does nothing but validate the OP's opinion that "'undefined behavior' is overused on SO just to justify downvoting someone if question is tagged c/c++."  It doesn't help him or anyone else write better code.

Comment: At the very least, "So ... is there anything (any contemporary compiler, hardware) that behaves differently than mentioned above?" is a question for hard facts, not opinions.

Comment: It is a survey question, and such are typically considered off-topic. I find it unlikely that any one person can answer for the behavior of all compilers on all platforms. Realistically, answers will be limited to some subset of implementations that the answerer considers to be significant.

Comment: That's true. On the other hand, if any such system exists, a correct answer doesn't rely on any one person answering for all other systems as well.

Comment: @hvd Then the question should probably be reworded as "Does anyone know of a C++ implementation that does not implement right shift of negative values as sign-preserving?"

Comment: @Casey:  I can answer that question.  **All** undefined behavior is by definition impossible to prove correct in the context of Standards-compliant C++.  The fact that some particular code is intended for a specific hardware stack is irrelevant.

Comment: @JohnDibling There is no undefined behavior here.

Comment: @Casey:  The question is about UB, not some specific little code snippet.

Comment: @Casey That's how I'm reading this question already. :) Actually though, thinking about it, any of those rare but existing implementations that don't use two's complement are probably sufficient as a counterexample for the purposes of the OP. The follow-up question, "okay... but how about any implementations that actually matter?", would definitely be opinion-based.

Comment: The only C compiler I've ever used which doesn't sign-extend right-shifts is Microchip's MCC18 PIC compiler (in general if you're looking for weird C semantics then look to microcontrollers, DSPs and mainframes). This has bitten me in actual code ported from other systems. Incidentally it also rounds down signed divisions instead of towards zero.

Answer (score 9):

> Why worry about 'undefined behavior' in >> of signed type?

Because it doesn't really matter how well defined any particular undefined behaviour is **now**; the point is that it may break at any point in the future. You're relying on a side-effect that may be optimized (or un-optimized) away at any point for any reason or no reason.

Also, I don't want to have to ask somebody with detailed knowledge of many different compiler's implementations before I use something I shouldn't use in the first place, so I skip it.

Comment: To complement what @meagar said about the future, you use 4 instead of sizeof(int) because that's easier, and then comes 64-bit computers and bit your a*s

Comment: @fernando.reyes: That's not the same. I think you miss my point. I do not think I will ever wake up and compilers will translate `>>` into sth. different than shift.

Comment: @Artur As you said "All compilers that I know translate...", you base the undefined-behavior-not-important assumption in the current state of compilers you know, but may a future compiler or one you don't know treat it differently and it will be undefined

Comment: @Artur: Actually, any decent compiler translates `2 >> 1` into a constant 1, so no assembler-level shift.

Comment: @Artur If we missed your point, it's because your question wasn't clear. *You asked* "why worry about undefined behaviour", not "do you think this will ever become defined behaviour".

Comment: @Vlad: You can think of many more cases where `>>` will just not matter at all. I am aware of constant folding etc.

Comment: @meagar: My bad. Indeed - maybe I should have asked if it is safe etc and if anyone would use it apart from me. Thanks anyways. I just thought my question will be highly downvoted but just not confirm I am right about downvoting the question was closed ;-)

Comment: Of course some undefined or implementation-defined behavior is cumbersome conform to, so in practice it's a trade-off between development time and portability. Not having to worry about 16-bit integers is a convenience which just might be worth it on some projects, and I think we can all agree on assuming more than 6 case-insensitive unique characters in external names in C89 code.

Comment: @Artur: again, this implies the mental model "statement-by-statement compilation with very local optimizations", which of course is not true. My point is that you can never predict which code is going to be produced by compiler, so the idea "`>>` is either shift or compile-time shift" doesn't reflect the truth.

Comment: @Vlad: Agreed. The problem is that many solutions are created 'kind of ugly/complicated' for the sole purpose of avoiding undefined bahaviors. I know compilation is close to - as you put it - "statement-by-statement" in debug mode but when optimizing various techniques are used. The problem is that compilers are not often that smart and this is what I worry about. If you for example use XOR for value swap (instead of swapping with temp) you assume 1) readers will know you swap 2) compiler can figure that out and optimize and not just translate one line by line. Hope now you know what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are compilers which behave different from what you assume.

In particular, optimization phases within compilers. These take advantage of the known possible values of variables, and will derive those possible values from the absence of UB. A pointer must be non-null if it's been dereferenced, an integer must be non-zero if it's been used as a divider, and a right-shifted value must be non-negative.

And that works back in time:

```
if (x<0) {
  printf("This is dead code\n");
}
x >> 3;
```

Comment: Signed right-shifts and signed integer division (in C89, not C99 or C11) are implementation-defined, not undefined behavior. On the vast majority of current compilers specifying arithmetic right-shift this works just fine.

Comment: @doynax: To me it looks like only you understood my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What it really comes down to is, are you willing to take the risk?

"The standard doesn't guarantee yada yada" is nice and all, but let's be honest now, the risk isn't big. If you're going to run your code on some crazy platform, you generally know in advance. And if it takes you by surprise, well, that's the risk you took.

Also, the workaround is horrible. If you're not going to need it, it's just polluting your codebase with pointless "function calls instead of right shifts" that will be harder to maintain (and thus carry a cost). And you'll never to able to "paste and forget" code from other places into the project - you'd always have to check the code for the possibility of right shifting negative signed integers.

Comment: The fact that right-shift is Implementation rather than Undefined serves as a critical check in the ability of obtuse compiler writers to mess with code which relies upon the behavior.  On a platform with 16/32-bit short/int, there's no reason `uint1=ushort1*ushort2;` shouldn't yield arithmetically-correct results 100% of the time for all combinations of operand, but on gcc it doesn't.