# Is it possible to disable warning on specific statements - Warnings treated as errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I added the following type to a header file

```
boost::function<void()> voidFunction;
```

and I get the following error

```
Error   291 error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated  
Warning 2   warning C4251: ....: class 'boost::function<Signature>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class ...
```

My question is if there is a way to disable the warning for this type only programatically without making changes to the project configuration. I am using visual studio 2006.Currently I have the option enabled for "treat warning as errors". I wanted to know if I can keep that setting there and add something programatically in code to ignore the warning introduced by adding the statement.

```
boost::function<void()> voidFunction;
```

Comment: One example is in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618480/vs2012-unsigned-negate

Comment: But more exactly your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159348/disable-single-warning-error